# Plot all ROC curves in one figure using KNeighborsClassifier with different k

Tags: python, roc

How can I plot multiple ROC curves using the algorithm KNeighborsClassifier? I want to plot a ROC curve for different k.

This is what I have, but it will plot different figures, and I want to combine all of them

```
k_range = range(1, 20)
for k in k_range:
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
    model = knn.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    y_predict_proba = model.predict_proba(X_test).tolist()
    probabilities = np.array(y_predict_proba)[:, 1]
    fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(Y_test, probabilities)
    # roc_auc = (auc(fpr, tpr))

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, color='darkorange', lw=2)
    plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', lw=2, linestyle='--')
    plt.xlim([-0.05, 1.05])
    plt.ylim([-0.05, 1.05])
    plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
    plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
    plt.title('ROC Curve')
    plt.legend(loc="lower right")
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong, in case anyone will ever want to do this:

```
for k in k_range:
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
    model = knn.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    y_predict_proba = model.predict_proba(X_test).tolist()
    probabilities = np.array(y_predict_proba)[:, 1]
    fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(Y_test, probabilities)
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
    color = ['blue', 'orange', 'red', 'green', 'coral',
             'grey', 'indigo', 'gold', 'lime', 'olive',
             'pink', 'navy', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'tomato',
             'turquoise', 'yellowgreen', 'maroon', 'lightblue']
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, color=color[k - 1], lw=1, label='ROC (area = %f)' % roc_auc)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', lw=2, linestyle='--')
plt.xlim([-0.05, 1.05])
plt.ylim([-0.05, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('ROC Curve')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```